# Alternatives à « Je pense que… »

Tags: vocabulaire, oral

J'ai un problème à l'oral, qui est que j'utilise toujours « je pense que » ; je voudrais y trouver des alternatives. J'utilise aussi parfois « à mon avis », mais il y a bien sûr beaucoup d'autres façons que je ne connais pas de dire la même chose.

Pouvez-vous me donner quelques alternatives ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- *Il me semble que*
- *D'après moi*
- *J'imagine que* marche souvent (proche de 'I guess' en anglais)
- *À mon sens* (i.e. « mon opinion est que »)
- *Je suis d'avis que/de*
- et « avoir dans l'idée » pour faire vraiment original.
- *(Il) m'est avis que* (pour attaquer les impersonelles à la mords-moi le nœud)
- *À ta place*…

Si mon problème, c'est que j'ai tendance à toujours parler de moi, je veux dire, que je parle toujours de moi à la première personne (normal, c'est moi), alors à ma place, j'utiliserai plus de tournures impersonelles :

Il est toujours possible de s'en sortir sans jamais explicitement mentionner aucun des interlocuteurs d'une conversation à laquelle on prend part. Il suffit de renouveler les façons d'aborder les choses, ce n'est pas foncièrement sorcier. Une bonne dose de pronoms relatifs, et c'est réglé. Il n'y a aucune difficulté inhérente au contour du problème, pour peu qu'on ait pas peur de tourner et de retourner la moindre de ses phrases, par le délicieux biais de tournures jamais moins alambiquées.

Comment: Et il y a aussi toutes les esbroufes type _À titre d'exemple..._, _Concrètement..._ Et on peut même tenter l'audacieux _Je vous écoute..._, qui, avec un peu d'entraînement, marche très bien.

Comment: @Istao : *Je vous écoute…* pour *Je pense que… X* me semble perdre le gros de l'idée exprimée au passage, non ?

Comment: C'était un peu par dérision que je disais ça, à propos de toutes ces formules qu'on entend pour faire semblant de prendre de la hauteur, mais qui expriment des idées très partisanes : _Je vous écoute : voulez-vous choisir entre le PSG et l'OM ? entre le fric et l'authenticité ? entre la frime et le sport ?_ Etc :-)

Answer (score 5):

Voici quelques variantes de « *Je pense que* » qui sont communément utilisées à l'oral. Elles laissent toutes la place à une éventuelle incertitude, mais elles ont souvent une autre caractéristique ; celle-ci est donnée à la suite, entre parenthèses. La liste commence par les tournures les plus impersonnelles :

- *Il semblerait que* (vraisemblance)
- *C'est possible que* (éventualité)
- *On dirait que* (apparence)
- *Je crois que* (conjecture — rarement croyance dans ce cas)
- *Il me semble que* (perception)
- *Je dirais que* (supposition)
- *Je trouve que* (position)
- *J'estime que* (jugement)
- *J'ai compris que* (déduction potentiellement erronée)
- *Je crois vraiment que* (foi)
- *Je suis persuadé que* (conviction)
- *Personnellement,* suivi de l'une des possibilités ci-dessus

De la même façon, « *à mon avis* » peut être remplacé par :

- *Probablement* (incertitude)
- *D'après moi* (thèse)
- *Pour moi* (conception)
- *De ce que j'en sais* (compréhension)
- *De mon point de vue* (subjectivité)